# How can I implement Google SameSite cookies on my website?

Tags: javascript, samesite

I am trying to implement SameSite cookies on my website, but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly, or even if it's working. Here is the code before I touched it:

```
    /**
    * Set cookie
    * @param {string} name - cookie name
    * @param {string} value - cookie value
    * @param {number} expiration - cookie expiration in minutes (-1 = cookies expire when browser is closed)
    */
    jQuery.fn.jplist.CookiesService.setCookie = function(name, value, expiration){

        var cValue = escape(value)
            ,exdate = new Date();

        expiration = Number(expiration);    

        if(expiration == -1 || isNaN(expiration)){
            document.cookie = name + "=" + cValue + ";path=/;";
        }
        else{
            exdate.setMinutes(exdate.getMinutes() + expiration); 
            document.cookie = name + "=" + cValue + ";path=/; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
        }       
    };
```

...and here is what I have done in my attempt to implement SameSite cookies. The only changes I made are adding 'SameSite=None,Secure' into the if/else statement:

```
    /**
    * Set cookie
    * @param {string} name - cookie name
    * @param {string} value - cookie value
    * @param {number} expiration - cookie expiration in minutes (-1 = cookies expire when browser is closed)
    */
    jQuery.fn.jplist.CookiesService.setCookie = function(name, value, expiration){

        var cValue = escape(value)
            ,exdate = new Date();

        expiration = Number(expiration);    

        if(expiration == -1 || isNaN(expiration)){
            document.cookie = name + "=" + cValue + ";path=/; SameSite=None,Secure";
        }
        else{
            exdate.setMinutes(exdate.getMinutes() + expiration); 
            document.cookie = name + "=" + cValue + ";path=/; SameSite=None,Secure; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
        }       
    };
```

Can anyone tell me if this is correct or if I have missed something? It's not clear to me when I test in the console.

Comment: just check developer console, application -> storage -> cookies, to see if your cookie was added?

Comment: When I check the cookies in the console, there doesn't seem to be any change at all. Most of my cookies are already SameSite=None and Secure. Maybe I'm editing the wrong file, but it's the only cookies.js file on our site.

Comment: I still don't know if it's working properly, but I found this article, which seems very helpful. I will have to wait and see if my implementation works. https://headerbidding.co/chrome-samesite-cookie-update/